# Not able to get response more than 50 items

Tags: sharepoint, yammer, yammer-api

Am trying to get follower_by users for specific user using yammer rest API.

It returns only 50 items and but actually I have 115 following.

Api url : /users/[userid]/followed_by.json

Answer (score 0):

Could be that you have a limit parameter set to 50